# Script to convert a txt file to a xml one

Tags: xml, text, matrix

How can I convert a set of txt files having data like this:

0.6613    0.4688  2.0165  1.0241  0.9544  1.8286  2.6666  2.6174  3.8877  1.4787  3.6946  2.7957  0.3338  0.3695  3.0863  1.1152  1.2474  0.3390  3.9634  4.0457  4.0211  3.8732  3.8479  4.0380  3.8116  3.7662  3.7878  3.7849  3.7670  3.7846  3.7931  3.8043  3.7668  3.8029  3.7851  3.8063  3.8167  3.8181  3.8012  3.8309  3.8331  3.8307  3.8467  3.8280  3.8547  3.8504  3.8394  3.8515  3.8658  3.8679  3.8691  3.8740  3.8735  3.8794  3.8782  3.9109  3.8806  3.8791  3.8723  3.8733  3.8651  3.8850  3.8900  3.8621  3.8876  3.8836  3.8860  3.8856  3.8808  3.8902  3.8878  3.8799  3.8753  3.8724  3.8796  3.8830  3.8848  3.8857  3.8882  3.8884  3.8919  3.8893  3.8836  3.8694  3.8718  3.8673  3.8906  3.8956  3.8735  3.8794  3.8782

into a xml file ?

Edit: I am working on windows 7, with Matlab and Visual c++ express.

Comment: In what environment/application/language?

Comment: You should be more specific. Simply wrapping the entire file in `<foo>...</foo>` would make it an XML file. What do you want the structure to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your language (or editor, if it is one-off) supports it, you could use a regex similar to the following...

Search:

```
(\d+\.?\d+)
```

Replace:

```
<node>\1</node>
```